# Is $Tor_A(k,k)$ a bicommutative Hopf algebra?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, hopf-algebras

Let $A$ be a commutative (or graded commutative) algebra over a field $k.$ In some sources, such as Mcleary's book on spectral sequences, Corollary 7.12, pg. 248, it is claimed that $\text{Tor}_A(k,k)$ is a bicommutative Hopf algebra. Is this a typo? Obviously, $\text{Tor}$ has a commutative algebra structure, but is it true that the coaddition is cocommutative?

Comment: What is the comultiplication? To get the multiplication we apply $\operatorname{Tor}_A(-,k)$ to $k \otimes k \rightarrow k$ and then precompose with the map $\operatorname{Tor}_A (k,k) \otimes \operatorname{Tor}_A (k,k) \rightarrow \operatorname{Tor}_A(k \otimes k,k)$. But to get the comultiplication it seems like we can't play the same game with $k \rightarrow k \otimes k$ since the canonical map $\operatorname{Tor}_A (k,k) \otimes \operatorname{Tor}_A (k,k) \rightarrow \operatorname{Tor}_A(k \otimes k,k)$ is in the wrong direction.

Comment: Proposition 7.10 gives the comultiplication: $[a_1,\dots, a_n] \rightarrow \Sigma [a_1, \dots, a_j] \otimes [a_{j+1},\dots,a_n]$.

Answer (score 9):

This is not true. Consider the algebra $A=T(V)/V^{\otimes 2}$, it is a commutative algebra whose augmentation ideal has zero multiplication. We have $\mathrm{Tor}_A(k,k)\cong T(V[1])$ with the shuffle product and deconcatenation coproduct, so the coproduct is very much noncommutative (it is the coproduct of the *cofree* conilpotent coalgebra co-generated by $V[1]$).

Comment: To me, this coproduct looks like the dual of something like the cup product which makes me think it should be cocommutative. Is this completely wrongheaded?

Comment: @ConnorMalin I can't guess your thinking process but one possibility is that you are confusing the concatenation product with the shuffle product?